# udpclient receive and broadcast problem

Tags: .net, vb.net, networking, asyncsocket, udpclient

I have this code that keeps giving me two problems.

first

> The requested address is not valid in its context

second , it receives broadcast it sends, i dont want this. I want only the listeneing server app to receive the broadcast

the sending code

```
Dim sendMessage As New structMessage
        sendMessage.Command = Command.IP
        Dim byteData As Byte() = sendMessage.ToByte()
        'Using UDP sockets

        epServer = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, iCurrUDPPort)

        'sckClientUDP.EnableBroadcast = True
        sckClientUDP.EnableBroadcast = True
        sckClientUDP.BeginSend(byteData, byteData.Length, _
                               CType(epServer, Net.IPEndPoint), _
                                New AsyncCallback(AddressOf sckClientUDP_DataArrival), _
                                Nothing)


        '## if server not found , increment port
        If iCurrUDPPort = iToPort Then
            iCurrUDPPort = iFromPort
        Else
            iCurrUDPPort = iCurrUDPPort + 1
        End If
```

The receiving code

```
    Private Sub sckClientUDP_DataArrival(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
        Try
            Dim remoteEP As EndPoint = Nothing
            sckClientUDP.EndReceive(ar, CType(remoteEP, IPEndPoint))
            'Convert the bytes received into an object of type Data
            Dim recvMessage As New structMessage(byteData)
            'Accordingly process the message received
            Select Case recvMessage.Command
                Case Command.IP
                    ServerIP = recvMessage.IP
                    ServerPort = recvMessage.Port
                    ' try connect here (TCP)
            End Select

            byteData = New Byte(1023) {}

            'Start listening to receive more data from the user
            sckClientUDP.BeginReceive(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf sckClientUDP_DataArrival), Nothing)
        Catch generatedExceptionName As ObjectDisposedException
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.Message)
        End Try
end sub
```

How do i fix this problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be broadcasting to an actual subnet IP address, not to IPAddress.Any.

Second, you cannot avoid the duplicated packet.  The broadcasting socket is supposed to receive the same packet it broadcasts. That is part of how broadcasting works.  You will have to filter out any unwanted packets by comparing their sender's IP address to your broadcasting IP address to see if they match.

Comment: thanks, but how do i detect the subnet my program is in in code?

Comment: You can use `IPAddress.Broadcast` instead of `IPAddress.Any` to broadcast to every subnet you are connected to. If you want to broadcast to specific subnets only, then you have to know what your assigned IP address and subnet mask are on each network, then you can format suitable broadcast IPs by masking the IP address with its subnet mask. This article shows you how to find the IPs and subnet masks in .NET 2.0+: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgorti/archive/2005/10/04/477078.aspx